# ValueError-The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it. Error during template rendering

Tags: django

I will user upload a pictur and I show it in a template.

I installed pillow and I added @property but problem doesnot solved.

```
my requirements.tct includes:
Django==2.2
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
Pillow==6.0.0
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0

in models.py 
class Melk(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image =  models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pic_folder', blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
            return self.image.url



in template
    <div class="page-header">        
      {% if show_mine %}
        <ul>
          <div class="row">
              {% for show in show_mine %}
              <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
                  <li>
                      {{ show.image.url | default_if_none:'#' }}                        
                      {{ show.city }}  
                  </li>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </ul>     
      {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Program works fine without image field. I expect user can see his uploaded image in a template.

Error is:

```
    ValueError at /users/home/
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/home/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Student\Desktop\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py in _require_file, line 38
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Student\Desktop\myproject\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is due to no file is linked to ImageField, place **{{ show.image.url }}** in an if condition like,

```
{% if show.image %}
   {{ show.image.url }} 
{% endif %}
```

Verify your file linking is working properly. you may add default value in ImageField as,

```
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True, default='/static/img/default-user.png')
```

or you may change your custom property like

```
@property
def image_url(self):
    if self.image:
        return self.image.url
    return '#'
```